# MySQL Trigger check if value exists in table of another DB

Tags: mysql

I need to create a trigger that **before insert** will check **if** the **username** that's trying to be added, **already exists** (case sensitive) in the table of another database (same mysql server).

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_user_insert BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF ( ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error message';
  END IF;
END
```

So, how can I make that **only if it exists in the table of the other database then insert the row.** and is there any better way to stop the insert other than `SIGNAL`?

Comment: I've never tried to do something like that, so I can't really help; but why would you even have users spread across databases like that? If you don't want them duplicating each other, why not have a single table shared between them?

Comment: @Uueerdo Yeah I know, I would have designed it like that, but unfortunately currently that's not an option.

Comment: If it the tables are similar enough, you could merge their data, and create a view in one schema that references the table in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_users
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.user = IF(EXISTS
 (
   SELECT * 
    FROM othertable 
   WHERE user IN(NEW.user)
 ), NULL, NEW.user);
```